Do I have to pay taxes on money I received for safekeeping from someone else in Germany?
I received 40k euros in the past year from a sibling living abroad in chunks of 5k. They transferred 20k into my Wise account and the other 20k directly into my local german bank account.
They transferred it using Wise and the money is legitimate, they have all the invoices and stuff for the services they provided and received this money from foreign clients. They had to transfer it to me for safekeeping because Wise was creating a lot of issues in their country and locking their account again and again, which made them weary and they sent the money to me purely for safekeeping purposes.
I am comparatively new in Germany but am I in trouble? Is it not allowed to receive money for safekeeping purposes? Would I need to declare it somewhere? Can't I tell my finanzamt that I dont intend to use this money it's just for safekeeping? Your help will be appreciated.

You might need to declare who is the actual owner of the money and identify them. This seems like a money laundering/tax evasion scheme, and the amounts are large enough (and split into suspiciously low amounts) that it might get noticed. In the US it would have been flagged for FinCEN, not sure how it works in Europe.

@littleadv That's what i need to know, how do i declare this and where. Maybe someone from Europe, specifically Germany can help.

In the US, you'd probably be able to report large international transfers to US customs and Border patrol via the "Currency Reporting Form." Failure to report such transfers has severe penalties (and probably risks the money being confiscated).  It would not surprise me if Germany had equivalent requirements.

@Brian no need to report bank transfer to CBP, only cash and instruments carried physically across the border

@TalhaImam as long as you can provide paperwork that proves the money is legit on request (and that you did not help your family to evade taxes), you are not in trouble for money laundering. I think your bigger risk is the "safekeeping" part - you need paperwork to prove that this is not a taxable gift (and in that case you probably violate the TOS of your bank, since by default you only may use your account on your on behalf, although I am not sure that would be enforced in such a case).

Considering the amount in question, it makes sense for you to consult a lawyer and to have the lawyer write a contract regarding that money. Then you and your sibling should each sign a copy.

The money might be interpreted as an interest-free loan from your sibling to you unless, as DJClayworth mentioned, you get the paperwork right. One has to pay taxes on very large gifts, and the difference between actual and market rate interest is a gift to you. Currently, siblings are tax-free for gifts up to €20,000 every ten years, and if you hold the money long enough you might approach that.
Similarly, if you should get into financial problems yourself, the money might be interpreted as yours and you might be expected to use it to cover your debts. (For instance, do you have a Haftpflichtversicherung and how much does it cover?)
Even if you are young and healthy, something might happen to you. It needs to be clear that they money is not part of your estate.
Sending the money in installments below €10 000 might be interpreted as money laundering. Better to send it all in one piece, and answer any questions from your bank about it.
And of course you should agree with your sibling how you will store the money (surely not "cash under your pillow"), what happens to any interest it earns, and what happens with risks if the deposit is not insured.


Does Germany have "donated interest"?

@DJClayworth; Germany has taxes on gifts (and inheritance, where the gift tax comes from). There are generous exempt amounts, so this does not usually come in, but a less-than-market-rate loan is a disguised gift.

@o.m. Thank you. This does help and aligns with what I have been reading. I have consulted professional advisors & it's expected i will hear from them today or tomorrow. For my specific case, there is no way I am allowed to use this money. Some people have told me that even if I send the money back to him now, the total money which was once received will still be considered as a whole since I had 40k once in my possession. It's this complexity because of which I havent yet returned his money. What do you think about this?

If the money is legit, you do not necessarily have to send it back. The important thing is to document everything, including things you do not expect to happen. That's where a lawyer or tax advisor can help.

As a rule of thumb, if the entire amount is considered a gift, then gift taxes would be due. If only the interest on the money is a gift that would be well below the tax threshhold. However for the tax office it is not clear from the outside which of the two situations applies.

@quarague, interest on €40k over ten years might come close to the €20k cutoff. Depends on how rates develop, and if there are further sums.

This isn't a specific answer for Germany, but general principles apply to most countries.
Yes, you are allowed to keep money for someone else.
No you do not have to pay taxes on it.
The essence of this is that the money is not "yours"; you are not using it or getting any benefit from it. You don't have to declare it on your tax forms. A key phrase is that you are "acting as an agent" for your sibling.
Having said that, it is likely that the tax authorities (if they find out about the money) will be suspicious that the money might have been given to you for your benefit, or as payment for something, rather than you holding it for safekeeping. If they suspect that then you might be in trouble unless you can show that their suspicions are untrue. I recommend these precautions:

Be very sure the money is legitimate, meaning it really is your sibling's and wasn't acquired illegally or from an illegal source. Hopefully this won't be a problem with your sibling, but I will mention it. The problems your sibling is having with Wise indicates that Wise thinks there may be a problem with the money, but that doesn't mean there is.
Get a written statement from your sibling that you are holding this
money for them; it should say how much it is, why they want you to
do it, and when and how the money will be returned to them.
Don't keep the money too long. The longer you keep it the deeper the suspicion that you are never going to give it back.
Keep the money separate from your money. In a separate account is ideal (even if it's an account in your name), but if you have to keep it in an account with your other money make sure that there is always 40k Euros in that account. Don't use any of it yourself, even if you can "pay it back" later. You should be able to show the tax authorities statements that show you had the money sitting in an account for the whole time you were looking after it.
Make sure you have complied with all money laundering regulations. Splitting a big transaction into smaller ones is often a red flag to law enforcement, who think you are trying to get round money reporting regulations.


Thank you for the information. I hope the information provided here is specifically relevant for Germany.

It's not specific to Germany, but general principles (and other countries) say you don't pay taxes on money that is not yours.

I am afraid EU has different regulations in place. They are not so easygoing even with small transfers.

The transfers aren't the issue the question or this answer are talking about. Do you have any evidence I'm wrong about the tax situation?
